# Using ggplot2, connect x- and y-coordinates by a third variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial

I would like to plot latitude vs longitude and connect the points via date and time, which I have stored in an object of class POSIXlt.  I have many, many GPS points, but here is a small set of them that I would like to plot using ggplot2.

My data are like so:

```
Description             lat         lon
6/16/2012 17:22         12.117017   -89.69692
6/17/2012 9:15          12.1178     -89.69675
6/17/2012 9:33          12.117783   -89.69673
6/17/2012 10:19         12.11785    -89.69665
6/17/2012 10:45         12.11775    -89.69677
6/17/2012 11:22         12.1178     -89.69673
6/17/2012 11:39         12.117817   -89.69662
6/17/2012 11:59         12.117717   -89.69677
6/17/2012 12:10         12.117717   -89.69655
6/16/2012 16:38         12.11795    -89.6965
6/16/2012 18:29         12.1178     -89.69688
6/16/2012 17:11         12.117417   -89.69703
6/16/2012 17:36         12.116967   -89.69668
6/16/2012 17:50         12.117217   -89.69695
6/16/2012 18:02         12.117583   -89.69715
6/16/2012 18:15         12.11785    -89.69665
6/16/2012 18:27         12.117683   -89.69632
```

I have a map that I am plotting these points onto.

I can plot the points just fine

```
plot1 <- map + geom_point(data=dat, aes(x = lon, y  = lat))
```

map is an object I made with `ggmap`, but it's not that important to include here.
The following code produces a line connecting points as `lon` increases

```
plot1+geom_line(data=dat, aes(x=lon,y=lat,colour="red"))
```

I can't figure out how to connect the points by the vector POSIXlt object `Description`
I know that in this small example I could easily reorder the points using something like `dat2 <- dat[with(dat, order(Description)), ]`, and remake plot1 using `dat2` and make the desired plot using the following code:

```
plot1+geom_path(data=dat2, aes(x = lond, y  = latd, colour="red"))
```

But for my much larger (hundreds of thousands of observations) dataset, this doesn't make sense as a solution without a bit more work to properly id each observation, which I will certainly end up doing anyway as part of additional data exploration.
Is there an argument I haven't discovered in geom_line for telling R how to connect the points?

I am admittedly still a novice at using ggplot2, and so, I apologize if I have missed something very simple.  I have been working on a lot of other code and learning, or at least using, several other packages, to work with this GPS data other spatial data available.  It's all a bit overwhelming... So many ideas, so little know-how! The larger point of this is to visualize (and eventually analyze) movement patterns and use of space by my study organisms, but for now, it would be great to visualize the data in a variety of ways to really get familiar with it.

If you have any recommended packages for working with spatial data and GPS data, I'd love to hear about them, as well.

Comment: The [**CRAN Task View: Spatial Data**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html) will tell you all you ever need to know (debatably!) about which packages to use in R for spatial data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the rows ordered by the date/time object to use `geom_path`. Since I think this is the best way to display the data we should focus on finding an efficient way to sort a large dataset. Obviously it would be good to get an idea of the scale of dataset you are working with. Millions of rows? Billions perhaps?!

Fortunately the `data.table` package does this very well indeed. Here is an example on a 1 million row table, with an ID column X, which the table is originally sorted on, an unsorted time column of 1 second observations, and two random columns for x and y, which takes < 1s on my laptop t sort according to date/time:

```
set.seed(123)
require(data.table)

#  Rows ordered on X, random order of unique date/time values of 1 second observations
df <- data.frame( ID = seq.int(1e6) , Desc = as.POSIXct(sample(1e6),origin=Sys.Date()) , x = runif(1e6) , y = runif(1e6) )
head(df)
#  ID                Desc         x         y
#1  1 2013-05-25 02:39:39 0.2363783 0.1387404
#2  2 2013-05-25 23:58:17 0.1192702 0.1284918
#3  3 2013-05-21 17:41:57 0.8599183 0.6301114
#4  4 2013-05-23 16:12:42 0.8089243 0.7919304
#5  5 2013-05-21 08:17:28 0.8197109 0.4568693
#6  6 2013-05-22 17:57:23 0.4611204 0.5358536
#  Convert to data.table
DT <- data.table(df)

#  Sort on 'Desc'
setkey(DT , Desc)
head(DT)
#          ID                Desc         x          y
#1: 544945 2013-05-18 01:00:01 0.7052422 0.52030877
#2: 886165 2013-05-18 01:00:02 0.2256636 0.04391553
#3: 893690 2013-05-18 01:00:03 0.1860687 0.30978506
#4: 932276 2013-05-18 01:00:04 0.6305562 0.65188810
#5: 407622 2013-05-18 01:00:05 0.5355992 0.98146120
#6: 138936 2013-05-18 01:00:06 0.5999025 0.81722902


#  Make data.frame to from this to use with ggplot2 (not sure if you can't just use the data.table directly)
df2 <- DT
```

So in your case you can try something like:

```
datDT <- data.table(dat)
setkey(datDT , Description)
dat2 <- datDT
```

Comment: `data.table` inherits from `data.frame` so you *should* be able to use it directly. If whatever function, `ggplot` in this case, does not have a method for `data.table`, then it will default to the method that is in place for `data.frame()`. Try running `str(dt`) or `class(dt)` to see that both `data.frame()` and `data.table()` are present.

Comment: @Frank `setkey` takes an unquoted column name. `setkeyv` can order on multiple column names but it takes a quoted character vector, not an unquoted list. So if using `setkeyv` use `setkeyv(datDT,"Description"). But if you are just ordering on one column just use `setkey(datDT,Description)`. You have to order the points because it plots points row by row and joins a line between them based on the row order. HTH!